# Split strings into 2 parts (strings have different patterns)

Tags: c#

I need help to develop a logic that allow me to locate the first part of a string in a collection of strings. Below are a few real sample data:

```
string s1 = "DARK BLUE          |d RBH 775  GREEN          |v BHM 554       |r 0012"
string s2 = "MEGA |m RMV 451X"
string s3 = "UPR  INT|c 0124  UPR|r 0006"
string s4 = "DARK GREEN  021|r 0004"
string s5 = "02.80|r x12  03.00|r calc"
string s6 = "03.33|r calc"
```

Expected output:

```
string out1[] = "DARK BLUE          ", "|d RBH 775  GREEN          |v BHM 554       |r 0012""
string out2[] = "MEGA ", "|m RMV 451X"
string out3[] = "UPR  ", "INT|c 0124  UPR|r 0006"
string out4[] = "DARK GREEN  ", "021|r 0004"
string out5[] = "02.80", "|r x12  03.00|r calc"
string out6[] = "03.33", "|r calc"
```

In general, all the strings comes with 2 patterns:

Pattern 1: (Value)(| with a letter)(Value)(| with a letter)...

Pattern 2: (Value) (Value)(| with a letter)(Key)(Value)(| with a letter)(Key)...

It is also possible to have the combination of pattern 1 and 2, i.e.: (Value)(| with a letter)(Value)(| with a letter)(Key)(Value)(| with a letter)..., but I don't think it matters too much because I just need to identify the pattern of the "first part"

**Notes**:
I was able to solve the problem on case by case basis:

For s1, s2, s5 and s6, I can just locate the index of first |, then take the substring of 0 to first pipe, and then the rest; For s3, I can locate the first "empty space" and take the substring; then for s4, I will locate the first |, and then locate the last "empty space" before the |, and take the substring.

The problem is: There are about 40,000+ strings, so it is almost impossible for me to split the string on case by case basis. I'm wondering if it is possible to write a logic that can split the string into 2 parts automatically?

> > Updated: Despite the 2 general patters, there are some slight variation for each pattern. For example, s1 and s2: There are spaces before the |, but s5 and s6 do not.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Under the "notes" include the methods that I have tried

Comment: So, if its SPACE PIPE, then split on that space.  But if there is a pipe in the word, split before the word?  And only do it for the first instance.

Comment: @paqogomez It doesn't work for s5 and s6 because there is nothing before the "pipe between words"

Comment: oh I see.. so i'm correct, but in addition if the line starts with a word that has a pipe, break on the pipe?

Comment: @paqogomez That's correct. "03.33|r calc" >>>>>> "03.33" and "|r calc"

Comment: I think your problem is that what you want to do is ill-defined, or at least you're not presenting it clearly to us.  Examples are good but it'd be nice to have clear logic.  If you have clear logic (if this then this, if that then that, etc) it becomes easy to translate into code

Comment: @j.i.h. I disagree. The method to split each pattern is very simple. (That's why I didn't bother to include the codes here as it will make the post way too lengthy). 

But it gets too complicated if i have all 2 patterns (plus variations) in one collection of strings, and this is where I'm stuck

Comment: @C.J. why dont you search the string for a specific piece you want, for example the pipe "|" and reference it's index position and enter that into your substring start or end position. what in each string is uniform regardlesss of the contents. what i see is the pipe.

Comment: Your patterns are a bit confusing, because a paren is used to create a group in regex.  You want only 2 groups per string, not several.

Comment: @Ron It is not possible. If you notice s3 and s4, the reference point is not "|", but an empty space. in addition to that, there are 40,000+ strings in the collection, there is no way I can tell you which string has which pattern (besides doing it manually)

Comment: @paqogomez I know it is very confusing. Welcome to the legacy data from the 1960s. Anyway, since I need to split the string into only 2 parts, do you think it is possible to use regex to identify only the first part of the string, split it, then concatenate with the rest?

Comment: I agree that regex is your animal.  It might be easier to swallow if you created a regex that only matched on one pattern, split on those, then move on to the others.  I would reccomend putting the regex tag into your question and phrasing it like "is this regex possible".  It would get the attention of those that are more ninja at regex than me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could solve this using a regular expression; but I'm by no means a regex expert. But from the information you've given, it's easy to code manually:

```
string[] Parse(string line)
{
    var chars = new List<char>(); // characters since last whitespace
    var all = new List<char>();

    using(var i = line.GetEnumerator())
    while(i.MoveNext())
    {
        var current = (char)i.Current;

        // keep track of characters since last whitespace
        if (current == ' ')      chars.Clear();
        else if (current != '|') chars.Add(current);

        // read until first pipe
        if(current == '|')
            return BuildResult(i, all, chars);

        all.Add(current);
    }

    return new String[]{};
}

string[] BuildResult(IEnumerator i, List<char> all, List<char> chars)
{
    var rest = (new[]{'|'}).Concat(ReadRemaining(i));
    var diff = all.Count - chars.Count;

    IEnumerable<char> start = chars;
    IEnumerable<char>   end = rest;
    if(diff != 0)
    {
        // if there was a whitespace, the chars 
        // before | belong to group 1
        start = all.Take(diff);
        end = chars.Concat(rest);
    }

    return new []{new String(start.ToArray()), new String(end.ToArray())};

}

string ReadRemaining(IEnumerator i)
{
    var rest = new List<Char>();
    while(i.MoveNext())
        rest.Add((char)i.Current);
    return new String(rest.ToArray());
}
```

The idea is the following:

- Walk over every char in the string until you hit a `|`.
- All characters before a whitespace belong to group 1.
- Decide if all characters that we've seen since the last whitespace belong to group 1 (case `s3` and `s4`) or group 2 (`s5` and `s6`) based on the fact if we've seen already a whitespace character.